# Search application.properties in directory external to jar spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There is an option to disregard the spring boot jar package application.properties file and
search the properties values ​​of the application.properties from a directory on the server.

On the server where we run the jar application with spring boot, I need the application to look up the properties values ​​of the application.properties file in another directory on the server, disregarding the existing **BOOT-INF\classes\application.properties** directory in the jar.

I would like to make an option to disregard the application.properties in jar spring boot generation and fetch the values ​​of an application.properties from a directory on the server.

This configuration would be for the application to work for each environment (production, approval and development) without the need for the developer to change the profiles in the application before the packaging.

Any examples of this setup?

Comment: While Christopher's answer is correct, you may want to consider the benefits of either using profiles and environment variables to identify the active profile (eg prod, dev, qa), or consider using something like spring-cloud-config.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html), you can pass inthe location of your externalised config using this:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=/path/application.properties
```

This command will support directories, provided `spring.config.name` matches the name of your config file.

Comment: Okay, I understood @ Christopher. I've looked in the https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files can I use the application.properties in subdirectories of the current directory etc. Which way is more appropriate or correct? Would you have any opinion?

Comment: I'm unsure if the flag supports relative paths - you'd need to test that out. Without knowing the specifics of your application requirements I couldn't possibly comment. My recommendation is usually to put these things in a single path, usually `/var` or something similar, then access absolutely.